# How to add dinamically a Spring MVC HandlerInterceptor using a Spring Post Processor

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am developing a jar that contains a Spring MVC Interceptor. I want that every Spring MVC Web app that adds that jar as a dependency gets the interceptor registered.

The target apps are configured with xml.

Inside my jar I could have a XML with:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/mynewinterceptor/**" />
        <bean class="com.codependent.myapp.interceptor.MyNewInterceptor">
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

this way the apps would import it and get the interceptor registered. However I want it to be transparent, that is to say, I want that just adding the jar they get the interceptor.

Notice all apps already scan a com.xxx.plugin package looking for beans. I guess it could be done with some kind of Spring post processor located in that package inside my jar...

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
@Configuration 
@ComponentScan({"com.include.your.jar.package"}) 
@EnableWebMvc   
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {  

    @Autowired
    private HandlerInterceptor[] inteceptors;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(inteceptors).addPathPatterns("/");     
    }
}
```

Comment: Those applications that will use the interceptors are already configured defining manually the different mvc elements: RequestMappingHandlerAdapter, RequestMappingHandlerMapping, message converters, exception resolvers. Won't @EnableWebMvc collide/override without control their own config?